# uwp programmatically scroll WebView up and down

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

I'm creating a simple news feed, and user can open a webview to see the details of the news, for some reason i want user can use buttons to control the webview scroll up and down instead of using scrollviewer, I have creat the webview to show the details but don't know how to scroll up and down using the buttons

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Answer (score 3):

> for some reason i want user can use buttons to control the webview scroll up and down instead of using scrollviewer.

For your requirement, you could use [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#methods_) method to notify `javaScrip` to invoke custom scroll method. For more please refer to [Interacting with WebView content.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#definition) And I have created a sample to achieve a simple page scrolling. Please refer to the following code:

**HtmlPage**

```
<body>
    <div id="test" style="width: 600px;height: 400px;padding: 10px;margin: 10px;border: 1px solid black;overflow:scroll;font-size:15px;line-height:200px;">
        Content
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ScrollDownBtn() {
            test.scrollTop += 10;
        }

        function ScrollUpBtn() {
            test.scrollTop -= 10;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<WebView x:Name="MyWebView" Source="ms-appx-web:///NewsPage.html" />
<StackPanel
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button
        x:Name="ScrollUp"
        Margin="10"
        Click="ScrollUp_Click"
        Content="ScrollUp" />
    <Button
        x:Name="ScrollDown"
        Margin="10"
        Click="ScrollDown_Click"
        Content="ScrollDown" />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void ScrollUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("ScrollUpBtn", null);
}

private async void ScrollDown_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("ScrollDownBtn", null);
}
```

[image]
This is code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/UwpScrollowButtonTest.git).

Comment: I create a HTML page(by right click the project and select "add new item") and try your code.  but it show me this error:  Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)

Comment: Before the page is rendered, running script becomes error.